# How to sort the values of one NSMutableArray using the value of another NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have one `NSMutableArray *arr1` with values:

```
{(B,abc) (E,pqr) (C,xyz)}
```

and another `NSMutableArray *arr2` with

`{(B) (C) (E)}`.

Now i want to sort `arr1` using `arr2` value so that `arr1` becomes `{(B,abc) (C,xyz) (E,pqr)}`. How can i do this?

Comment: [WAT?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) Does the first array contain arrays? Dictionaries? Or something else?

Comment: arr1 contains 3 arrays each with above values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    NSMutableArray *unsortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"B",@"abc", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"E",@"pqr", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"C",@"xyz", nil],nil];
    NSArray *guideArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"B",@"C",@"E", nil];

    for(int i=0; i< [guideArray count];i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< [unsortedArray count];j++)
        {
            if([[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:j] containsObject:[guideArray objectAtIndex:i]])
            {
                [unsortedArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:j withObjectAtIndex:i];
                break;                
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",unsortedArray);
```

I have tested this and working for me. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Nah, not this, please, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems you have an array and an array of arrays:

```
NSArray *sorter = @[@"B", @"C", @"E"];
NSMutableArray *sortee = [@[
    @[@"B", @"abc"],
    @[@"E", @"pqr"],
    @[@"C", @"xyz"]
] mutableCopy];

[sortee sortUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
    NSString *s1 = [o1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *s2 = [o2 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSInteger idx1 = [sorter indexOfObject:s1];
    NSInteger idx2 = [sorter indexOfObject:s2];
    return idx1 - idx2;
}];
```